# FFMPEG : Fill/Change (part of) audio waveform color as per actual progress with respect to time progress

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to make command which is generating waveform from mp3 file and show on background image and play audio.
Togethr with this, I want to change waveform color left to right (something like progressbar) as per overall video time elapses.

I have created following command which shows progress bar using drawbox to fill box color as per current time position.

ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -threads 0 -i sample_background.png -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "color=red@0.5:s=1280x100[Color];[0:v]drawbox=0:155:1280:100:gray@1:t=fill[baserect];[1:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwaves=s=1280x100:rate=7:mode=cline:scale=sqrt:colors=0xffffff[waveform]; [baserect][waveform] overlay=0:155 [v1];[v1][Color] overlay=x='if(gte(t,0), -W+(t)*64, NAN)':y=155:format=yuv444[v2]" -map "[v2]" -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -crf 35 -ss 0 -t 20 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 output_withwave_and_progresbar.mp4

[image]

But I want to show progress inside generated audio waveform instead of making / filling rectangle using drawbox.

So I have tried to make 2 waveform of 2 different color and overlay on each other and I wanted to show such a way that top waveform should display only part from x position (left) respective to current time.

ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -threads 0 -i sample_background.png -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:v]drawbox=0:155:1280:100:gray@1:t=fill[baserect];[1:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwaves=s=1280x100:rate=7:mode=cline:scale=sqrt:colors=0xff0000[waveform];[1:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwaves=s=1280x100:rate=7:mode=cline:scale=sqrt:colors=0xffffff[waveform2]; [baserect][waveform] overlay=0:155 [v1];[v1][waveform2] overlay=x='if(gte(t,0), -W+(t)*64, NAN)':y=155:format=yuv444[v2]" -map "[v2]" -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -crf 35 -ss 0 -t 20 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 test.mp4

But I am not able to find way to do Wipe effect from left to right, currently it is sliding (as I am changing x of overlay)
It might be done using alpha merge and setting all other pixel to transparent and only show pixels which are less than x pos.
but I am not able to find how to do this.

Background image:
[image]

we can use any mp3 file file, currently I have set 20 sec duration.

Can someone please guide how we can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the blend filter i.e.

`ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -threads 0 -i sample_background.png -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:v]drawbox=0:155:1280:100:gray@1:t=fill[baserect];[1:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,asplit[red][white];[red]showwaves=s=1280x100:rate=7:mode=cline:scale=sqrt:colors=0xff0000[red];[white]showwaves=s=1280x100:rate=7:mode=cline:scale=sqrt:colors=0xffffff[white];[red][white]blend=all_expr='if(lte(X/W,T/64),A,B)'[waveform];[baserect][waveform]overlay=0:155:format=yuv444[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -crf 35 -ss 0 -t 20 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 test.mp4`

where `64` is total duration of audio.

Comment: Thank you so much @Gyan for your quick answer. It works perfectly.

Comment: I am using this command to create soundwaves on an image, everything is good except the soundwaves are only creating in the middle of the video. Is it possible to move the soundwaves to the top/bottom of the image in the video?  `ffmpeg -i kina_can_we_kiss_forever.mp3 -i 'w.jpg' -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:colors=white,format=yuva420p[v];[1:v]scale=1280:720[bg];[bg][v]overlay[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mov`

Comment: Change overlay to `overlay=y=X` where X is vertical position.