# FFMPEG : Set Opacity of audio waveform color

Tags: ffmpeg

I was trying to do transparency in waveform generated. It seems there is not direct option in 'showwaves' filter so I came across 'colorkey' which might help.

I am trying with following:

ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -threads 0 -i background.png -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwaves=s=1280x100:rate=7:mode=cline:scale=sqrt:colors=0x0000ff,colorkey=color=0x0000ff:similarity=0.01:blend=0.1[v]; [0:v][v] overlay=0:155 [v1]" -map "[v1]" -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -crf 35 -ss 0 -t 5 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 test_org.mp4

So I wanted to blue color waveform and wanted to set opacity of that 1 to 0 let say. But it seems this generates blackbox which is actual background of '1280x100'. I want to keep background of waveform transparent and just wanted to change opacity of waveform only.

Result of my command: enter image description here

[image]

Can you please let me know your suggestion

@Gyan, this is with reference to following question which you have answered.

[Related last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792396/ffmpeg-fill-change-part-of-audio-waveform-color-as-per-actual-progress-with/51817942?noredirect=1#comment90590615_51817942)

Thanks, Hardik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need colorkey.

Change `colors=0x0000ff` to `colors=0x0000ff@0.5` for 50% transparency.

Comment: Thank @Gyan, I thought "@" will not work so was thinking complex way :( but it was really simple one. Thanks for pointing out. It works great!