# "Smooth" the ffmpeg showwaves video filter output

Tags: ffmpeg

I think I'm close to what I'm after, thanks to excellent answers like: [FFMPEG : Fill/Change (part of) audio waveform color as per actual progress with respect to time progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792396/ffmpeg-fill-change-part-of-audio-waveform-color-as-per-actual-progress-with?rq=1) ...but not quite there!

I'm scripting the generation of a waveform video with `showwaves`, and overlaying that onto a static image background, turning the whole thing into video. All is well, except I'd like to "smooth" the waveform. In most tutorials/answers you will see jagged "peaks" in the waveform animation, as of course the audio data varies widely into peaks and troughs. (The differences expressed between the lowest and highest amplitude (I think) in each audio frame sample.) I'd like to get more of a consistent "flowing wave", without the sharp spikes up and down.

Currently using the filter much as described in the previous link:

```
[1:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,asplit[red][white]; \
[red]showwaves=s=1280x100:rate=15:mode=cline:scale=sqrt:colors=0xff0000[red]; \
```

Which results in the following (ignoring the red on white overlay, which I may drop):

[Current v desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvPJJ.png)

This generates the type of wave plot I want (solid vs a sine, for example), but I *think* I need to either tweak the audio stream or...possibly post filter the `showwaves` video stream (but I think the former) to get the effect I want. I tried to reduce the `rate` of `showwaves` but that just results in juddery video. So to me that feels like the audio data needs to be the changed factor.

My limited audio knowledge leads me to think I should gain, compress, normalize, or all of the above, the audio input, which I have tried, but can't seem to nail it. Keep in mind the audio stream in this filter chain is purely feeding the `showwaves` filter, so I can "trash" it as much as needed in order to get the visualization I want.

I hope this all makes sense, and if I need to provide more info, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?